# mod_rewrite for SEO friendly URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I am trying to write SEO friendly URL of below URL.

```
www.url.com/item.php?id=_84_113_112&lang=en
```

I have written below code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ item.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But not working, can anyone help?

Comment: `)/$` force it to ends with `/` shoud be `)$`

Comment: .htaccess and SEO doesn't have anything to do with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably extra `/` at the end (before $) is the problem.
Change it to like this.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ item.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ item.php?id=$1&lang=$2
```